# Hiding div when page loads and display the same after few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div which i want to hide when the page loads and want to display the same after few seconds.how do i do this using jquery.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="bio1">
<div class="carousel_titles">
    <h6>Saul Yarmak</h6>
        <div class="ops">Chairman & CEO</div>
     </div>
     <div class="img_block wrapped_imgs">
        <img src="img/pictures/team1.jpg" alt="Tom" />
     </div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should hide it by default using css:

```
#bio1 {
    display:none;
}
```

and then you can use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to show it after a few seconds:

```
$('#bio1').delay(3000).fadeIn();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmrM4/)**

Answer (score 2):

Start with it hidden:

```
#bio1{
    display:none;
}
```

When the page is ready, create a timeout function, then after 3000 MS (3 seconds), show the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#bio1').show(1000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/DFqp3/1/)**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  
    var hashes ="#a1_bio"; 
      $(hashes).hide();
        setTimeout(function()
                   {
                        $(hashes).fadeIn();
                   },2000)
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this Fiddle demo :-

css

```
#bio1 {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#bio1').show();",3000 ); // Display div after 3 second
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ6y4)